# How do I call this override function from a different file

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to call a function from another file. The other file has the function I need and swift does not support multiple inheritance.

I was trying to combine this file-

```
import XLPagerTabStrip
//Delete UIViewController, and Extend //ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController instead
class ParentViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {
    let purpleInspireColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.03, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

    // change selected bar color
    settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = .white
    settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .white
    settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = purpleInspireColor
    settings.style.buttonBarItemFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 2.0
    settings.style.buttonBarMinimumLineSpacing = 0
    settings.style.buttonBarItemTitleColor = .black
    settings.style.buttonBarItemsShouldFillAvailiableWidth = true
    settings.style.buttonBarLeftContentInset = 0
    settings.style.buttonBarRightContentInset = 0
    changeCurrentIndexProgressive = { [weak self] (oldCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, newCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, progressPercentage: CGFloat, changeCurrentIndex: Bool, animated: Bool) -> Void in
    guard changeCurrentIndex == true else { return }
    oldCell?.label.textColor = .black
    newCell?.label.textColor = self?.purpleInspireColor
    }
    }

    override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    let child_1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Phone")
    let child_2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Email")
    return [child_1, child_2]
    }
}
```

with this file -

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SignupViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
           let loginViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
           present(loginViewController,animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
    override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    let child_1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Phone")
    let child_2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Email")
    return [child_1, child_2]
    }
}
```

However, they inherit from two different base classes so nothing has worked yet.

I thought to place both classes in separate files and call functions from the class in the file I need to use however I am having an issue with the arguments when I call this particular function.

```
    override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    let child_1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Phone")
    let child_2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Email")
    return [child_1, child_2]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create some global function (outside of any class) with the common code and as far as I can see you don't need any parameters

```
func instantiatePhoneAndMailViewControllers() -> [UIViewController] {
    return [UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Phone"), 
            UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Email")]
}
```

and call it from within `viewControllers(for:)` etc. For instance

```
override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    return instantiatePhoneAndMailViewControllers()
}
```